# JavaScript how to refer to button generated by for

Tags: javascript, html

I I generate a table of data in a loop. Each line has its own button.

```
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        function liste() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.addEventListener('load', function(data) {
                var site = JSON.parse(data.target.responseText);
                var new_html = '';
                    new_html += '<table class="table table-responsive">';
                    new_html += '<thead>';
                    new_html +='<tr>';
                    new_html +='<th>delete</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>id</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>lieu</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>type</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>latitude</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>longitude</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>tarif</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>date</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>photo</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>prenom</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>nom</th>';
                    new_html +='<th>commentaire</th>';
                    new_html +='</tr>';
                    new_html +='</thead>';
                    new_html +='<tbody>';
                    for (var i1 in site){
                    new_html +='<tr id="row"'+i1+'>';
                    new_html +='<td>';
                    new_html +='<button id="delete" class="btn btn-success topbuttons">DELETE</button>';
                    new_html +='</td>';
                    for (i2 in site[i1]){
                    new_html +='<td>';
                    if(i2 == 'photo'){
                    new_html += '<img src="'+site[i1][i2]+'" width="300" height="200">';
                    }else{
                    new_html += site[i1][i2];
                    }
                    new_html +='</td>';
                    }
                    new_html += '</tr>';                
                    }

                document.querySelector('#resultat').innerHTML = new_html;
            });


            request.open("GET", "webservice_liste_get.php?search="+document.getElementById('search').value);
            request.send();
        }
    });
    </script>

<div id="resultat"></div>
```

I have a problem with writing action listener for button so that when you click on the button appeared message: you clicked on the row number `$id`. How can I do this?

Comment: you have to either convert the button to a HTML element , bind click and append inner or in the button string add onclick attribute.

Comment: How to do it? Button is placed in the table which is generated by js.

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we can reproduce your issue. You are for more likely to get an answer if you make your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't generate multiple `id="delete"` buttons. `id` attribute should be unique. Do this `new_html +='<button id="delete' + i1 + '" class="btn btn-success topbuttons">DELETE</button>';` instead.

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

2. When you generate DOM elements you have to bind the events (`click` for example) **after** it. If those elements was generated from the response's ajax request, you have to bind their event after they are added to the DOM.

So, the easy way, use jQuery `on` event like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  function liste() {
    //var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //request.addEventListener('load', function(data) {
      //var site = JSON.parse(data.target.responseText);
      var site = [{id:1, name: 2}, {id:1, name: 2}, {id:1, name: 2}];
      var new_html = '';
      new_html += '<table class="table table-responsive">';
      new_html += '<thead>';
      new_html +='<tr>';
      new_html +='<th>delete</th>';
      new_html +='<th>id</th>';
      new_html +='<th>lieu</th>';
      new_html +='<th>type</th>';
      new_html +='<th>latitude</th>';
      new_html +='<th>longitude</th>';
      new_html +='<th>tarif</th>';
      new_html +='<th>date</th>';
      new_html +='<th>photo</th>';
      new_html +='<th>prenom</th>';
      new_html +='<th>nom</th>';
      new_html +='<th>commentaire</th>';
      new_html +='</tr>';
      new_html +='</thead>';
      new_html +='<tbody>';
      for (var i1 in site){
        console.log(i1);
        new_html +='<tr id="row'+i1+'">';
        new_html +='<td>';
        new_html +='<button id="delete" class="btn btn-success topbuttons">DELETE</button>';
        new_html +='</td>';
        for (i2 in site[i1]){
          new_html +='<td>';
          if(i2 == 'photo'){
            new_html += '<img src="'+site[i1][i2]+'" width="300" height="200">';
          }else{
            new_html += site[i1][i2];
          }
          new_html +='</td>';
        }
        new_html += '</tr>';                
      }

      document.querySelector('#resultat').innerHTML = new_html;
    //});


    //request.open("GET", location.href);
    //request.send();
  }
  
  document.querySelector('#resultat').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var clickedEl = event.target;
    if(clickedEl.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      alert(clickedEl.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));
    }
  });
  
  liste();
});
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search" />
<div id="resultat"></div>
```

Comment: It is possible to do this without jquery?

Answer (score 2):

While all browsers will parse `.innerHTML`, the canonical way to add content to a page in JavaScript is through the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) methods which interact with Node and Element objects instead of concatenating strings together.

`document.createElement('tagname');` creates blank elements.
`element.id = 'myid';` sets the id attribute.
`element.className = 'class';` sets the whole class attribute.
`element.classList.add('classname');` adds a class...

Different elements will have specific properties as well, such as the `HTMLImageElement` which has a `.src` property. These properties all directly map to the tag attributes.

The older way to set the text of an element was do create a Text node and append it to the element. 
`element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('mytext'));`
Modern browsers support the shorthand `textContent` property which allows you to just do
`element.textContent = 'mytext';` which should be cleaner than using `.innerHTML` which has to get parsed.

If you start creating content dynamically with these, you'll be able to bind events to them as well:

```
function buttonClickListener(e) {
  alert('You clicked on the button with id = ' + e.currentTarget.id);
}

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.id = 'delete';
button.className = 'btn btn-success topbuttons';
button.textContent = 'DELETE';

button.addEventListener('click', buttonClickListener);
```

But it you don't want to restart you current code, you might just want to retrieve all buttons from the code you get in HTML. You can retrieve elements with a CSS selector in the `querySelectorAll` method.

```
var resultat = document.querySelector('#resultat');
resultat.innerHTML = new_html;
// select all button elements in resultat
var buttons = resultat.querySelectorAll('button');

for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; ++i) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', buttonClickListener);
}
```

Now I'm not sure exactly what you wanted to detect and what message you wanted to show, but the tools are in your hands :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (var i1 in site){

    new_html +='<tr id="row"'+i1+'>';
    new_html +='<td>';
    new_html +='<button id="delete" data-row-id="' + i1 +'" class="btn btn-success topbuttons" onclick="clickHandler(this)">DELETE</button>';
    new_html +='</td>';
```

...

```
function clickHandler(el){
    alert("You\'ve clicked on the row with number: " + el.getAttribute('data-row-id'));
}
```